# Get Android application package name from android app labels?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Is there any way to get package names using the app name? For example, if I type *whatsapp* and the app is installed on device, then it should return the package name like *com.whatsapp*

Comment: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android then just iterate through all apps using a for-loop and pick the matching one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    public static void installedApps()
{
    List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
        if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
        {
            String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
           // use if(appName.equals(YOUR_APP_NAME))
        }
    }
}
```

You can get app name, pakage name, app version name, app version code, app icon.

Create a Modal class for all this (Data Structure)

**ModalApps.java**

```
   public class ModalApps {
    public String appname = "";
    public String pname = "";
    public String versionName = "";
    public int versionCode = 0;
    public Drawable icon;

}
```

Now `getPackages()` will return info of all packages

```
private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}
```

Now

```
    private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Using this `ArrayList` you can create package name corresponding to the app name.

Comment: This sounds great ,  have to try this .  actually i want to get app icon according to the app label .